# Mysql query to print the database values in alternative way

Tags: mysql, select

i have one database  table which ihave to print in last following way

```
+---+--------+-----+    
|id | cat_id | name|    
+---+--------+-----+     
|1  |   1    | b   |    
|2  |   1    | ba  |    
|3  |   2    | c   |    
|4  |   2    | ca  |    
+---+--------+-----+
```

i need a mysql query which will print this table in the following way

```
+---+--------+-----+    
|id | cat_id | name|    
+---+--------+-----+     
|1  |   1    | b   |    
|3  |   2    | c   |    
|2  |   1    | ba  |    
|4  |   2    | ca  |    
+---+--------+-----+
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You have to specify, how you want to order it. Only the length of the field, or also alphabetically?

Comment: Actually i need in the order of the "cat_id" not alphabetically..

Comment: Then your question is incorrect. You desired output isn't ordered by the cat_id

Comment: Please define your desired result with all rules as exactly as possible.

Comment: maja -- i need in the GROUP BY cat_id,  not in the order by

Comment: `GROUP BY` means, that you collect several rows, and return only one of them. Don't tell us what you need, tell us what you want to achieve.

Comment: see i have a list of cat_id, 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 this way .. okey . but i expect in the serial order 1 2 3 again 1 2 3 again 1 2 3.

Comment: Ok, in that case, you will need a subquery. I would also consider taking a look at the database-layout, because this kind of problem seems to be very strange.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from (
    select
    t.*,
    @catwise_rownum := if(@prevcat != cat_id, 1, @catwise_rownum + 1) as rownum,
    @prevcat := cat_id
    from
    your_table t,
    (select @catwise_rownum:=0, @prevcat:=null) var_init
    order by cat_id, id
) sq
order by rownum, cat_id
```

- see it working live in an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/05c14/2/0)

Comment: is there a possibilty to without creating a another column how to sort and get the result

Comment: Glad I could help. I see no way to solve this without this column.